# Read numbers from formatted file in Python

Tags: python, input, numpy

I have file with k columns of numbers (same number of elements for each columns). What is the fastest way to read it and save the numbers in each column in a separate numpy.array?

Comment: Hi Bob, is this homework? If it is could you please tag it as such? Also, is there any source code you can show us to help us understand how much you've tried yourself? Would it be possible for you to show us a sample of the file you're trying to read?

Answer (score 3):

Try using [`genfromtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html).

This has the benefit of you being able to specify column names if you like, or even read into a `recarray`.

I made a file 'tmp':

```
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15
```

Then from numpy:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.genfromtxt('tmp')
#array([[  1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,   5.],
#       [  6.,   7.,   8.,   9.,  10.],
#       [ 11.,  12.,  13.,  14.,  15.]])
```

If you look at `help(np.genfromtxt)` you'll see there are various options like specifying custom `dtype`s (so you can make a recarray if you want), setting options for missing values, reading in column names, etc.

Comment: would it be possible to store the columns into separate variables, assuming you know the number of columns?

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.loadtxt('yourfile.txt')
>>> print a
[[  1.   2.   3.   4.   5.]
 [  6.   7.   8.   9.  10.]
 [ 11.  12.  13.  14.  15.]]
>>> columns = dict(enumerate(a.T))
>>> columns[0]
array([  1.,   6.,  11.])
>>> columns[1]
array([  2.,   7.,  12.])
```

Comment: note you could also simply use `columns = a.T`, because numpy arrays are row-major iterable anyway.

Answer (score 0):

open() returns a file object, and is most commonly used with two arguments: open(filename, mode).

> > > f = open('/tmp/workfile', 'w')
> > >       print f

The first argument is a string containing the filename. The second argument is another string containing a few characters describing the way in which the file will be used. mode can be 'r' when the file will only be read, 'w' for only writing (an existing file with the same name will be erased), and 'a' opens the file for appending; any data written to the file is automatically added to the end. 'r+' opens the file for both reading and writing. The mode argument is optional; 'r' will be assumed if it’s omitted.

On Windows, 'b' appended to the mode opens the file in binary mode, so there are also modes like 'rb', 'wb', and 'r+b'. Python on Windows makes a distinction between text and binary files; the end-of-line characters in text files are automatically altered slightly when data is read or written. This behind-the-scenes modification to file data is fine for ASCII text files, but it’ll corrupt binary data like that in JPEG or EXE files. Be very careful to use binary mode when reading and writing such files. On Unix, it doesn’t hurt to append a 'b' to the mode, so you can use it platform-independently for all binary files.